# Gradle error in Android Studio: AndroidSdk.SendPing failed, Firebase client lib not compiling

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

When inserting a new activity (more specifically, navigation drawer activity) my gradle sync breaks and throws the following error:

```
Failed to find: com.firebase:firebase-client-android:1.1.0.0
```

I *could* undo the changes, but I would like to understand why gradle breaks while adding new activities.

Looking over the IDEA LOG, I came by the following Warning:

```
2014-11-20 15:53:26,547 [ 788010]   WARN - ea.stats.LegacySdkStatsService - AndroidSdk.SendPing failed 
java.net.UnknownHostException: tools.google.com
```

I figure it has something to do with the Gradle build file, but I'm not entirely sure why it would compile the Firebase library before adding an activity and after, not.

I'm running on a MacBook Air, OS X Yosemite.

**build.gradle:** https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/82fe78f7bc2c9064986b
**Idea log:** https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/d38949010198ec950acd

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by deleting the library from gradle dependencies, and searching for the library in Maven Central (in this case, Firebase) and adding the latest version.